# rails joins with module name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is how to join two models

```
User.where(:id => 1).joins(:posts)
```

but how to join two models with module/namspace

```
@schedules= Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:Swimming::Slot).where(:date => @date)
```

seems not working properly (with error message)

```
:Swimming is not a class/module
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated to 
    @schedules= Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:swimming_slots).where(:date => @date)

and I do have this table

```
create_table :swimming_classschedules do |t|
  t.integer :slot_id
  t.integer :coach_id
  t.integer :level_id
  t.string :note

  t.timestamps
end


create_table :swimming_slots do |t|
  t.string :date
  t.string :start
  t.string :end

  t.timestamps
end
```

Howcome I got this error

```
Association named 'swimming_slots' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

**update 2**

add this line to Swimming::Classschedule module

belongs_to :swimming_slots ,:class_name=>'Swimming::Slot',:foreign_key => "slot_id"

and

change joins to

```
@schedules= Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:swimming_slots).where(:swimming_slots =>{:date => @date})
```

Now it works

Comment: `:Swimming::Slot` is not a valid Ruby expression. If you want a module, it is `Swimming::Slot`. If you want a symbol, it is `:"Swimming::Slot"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you pass the association name to joins. for example, if you have an association like

```
has_many :swimming_slots, class_name: 'Swimming::Classschedule'
```

then you pass `swimming_slots` and rails will do the joins for you.

```
User.joins(:swimming_slots)
```

UPDATE:

if `slot_id` refers to a record in the `swimming_slots` table, you should have something like

```
belongs_to :slot, class_name: 'Swimming::Slot'
```

in your class schedule model.  If you have that, you should be able to do

```
Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:slot)
```